# Matching records between 2 access tables

Tags: database

All,

I have 2 tables in Access. Let's call them RepQ1 and Des. There are 2 fields in these 2 tables which I am trying to match and get matching records. These 2 fields are of TEXT data type. Following is the query that I am using.

SELECT * FROM RepQ1 LEFT JOIN Des ON Rep.Mat=Des.MatD;

When I run this, I get no result displayed. Please advise.

Comment: If you want simple matched records then you can remove `left join` and perform simple where query.  `select * from repq1 as r, des as d where r.mat=d.matD`. Make sure you have matching records in your database

Comment: It means then nothing is matching in your tables.

Comment: @ Sagar, there are matching records. Else no point in me asking this question.                                                                                                                                                                                                                   @Manoj, Thank you. I tried your approach as well. Unfortunately nothing still comes up. I do not understand as to why. These 2 fields are TEXT fields. There are records matching as I tried a VLOOKUP in Excel and I get the result. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this query

`SELECT * FROM RepQ1 WHERE RepQ1.Mat IN (SELECT DISTINCT MatD FROM Des);`